# Get custom element via screenscraping with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to screenscrape some prices from yahoo finance for some stocks in my excel sheet.

My approach is to use:

```
Function Scrape()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With appIE
        .Navigate "https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set data = appIE.document.getElementById("data-reactid") #this is the point where I'm stuck

End Function
```

The question I have is how to get the custom elements such as:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="32">1.025,05</span>
```

The site seems to use `reactid` for every element which makes it easy to pinpoint the elements. How would I go by doing that for the above example `data-reactid="32"`

Thanks

Comment: There are around `9` elements as of now in that page if you look for `data-reactid="32"`. Check out [this image](https://imgur.com/9O42fbg) to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using xhr because the content you look for is available in the page source. This is one of the efficient ways how you can go:

```
Public Sub GetPrice()
    Const Url$ = "https://de.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA"
    Dim S$, itemPrice$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
         itemPrice = .getElementById("quote-market-notice").ParentNode.FirstChild.innerText
        MsgBox itemPrice
    End With
End Sub
```